# C++11 constexpr variadic logic expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, constexpr

I was trying to use variadics templates for test certain propierties (type_trait) at compile time, but seems the following code can't compile

```
template<typename test>
constexpr bool trait_test(){
    return test::value;
}

template<typename test, typename... Others>
constexpr bool trait_test(){
    return test::value&&trait_test<Others...>();
}

template<typename A, typename... Deriveds>
constexpr bool commonBaseClass{
    return trait_test<std::is_base_of<A,Deriveds>...>();
}
```

The problem seems to be that when "Others" has a lenght of 0 there are 2 possible calls

```
trait_test<typename test>
trait_test<typename test, typename... Others={}>
```

and the compiler don't know wich one to peek. I want of course to peek the first one (and keep everything constexpr)

Comment: Please include an http://sscce.org in your question next time. This makes it much easier for others to test your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal change to get your code compiling would be to replace your second `test_trait` overload with:

```
template<typename T0, typename T1, typename... Others>
constexpr bool trait_test(){
  return T0::value&&trait_test<T1, Others...>();
}
```

which means 1 argument *only* matches the first, and 2 or more match the second.

Comment: mmm T0 is not evaluated, so I have to pass dummy type, but if I do so, when I call <dummy,T1> this results in:
T1::value&&T1::value, so T1 get evaluated twice. wich is ok in this case because False&&False = False and TRue&&True = True, but is not applicable to other cases (for example if && is replaced by "xor"). Because if A xor 1 = 1 then A xor 1 xor 1 = 0. Also not applicable in most generale case without "constexpr".

Comment: Should accept this answer now, the other answer does not compile on VS 2013. so this one is "more portable".

Answer (score 2):

Indeed that is ambiguous. The function template accepting one template argument is not more specialized than the function template accepting 1 or more template arguments, because partial ordering of function templates is done on *function* arguments - and both function templates have zero function arguments.

If I may suggest an alternative approach:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Ts>
struct all_of;

template<typename T>
struct all_of<T> : std::integral_constant<bool, T::value> { };

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct all_of<T, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<bool, 
    T::value && all_of<Ts...>::value> { };

template<typename A, typename... Deriveds>
constexpr bool commonBaseClass()
{
    return all_of<std::is_base_of<A, Deriveds>...>();
}
```

You would then use your `commonBaseClass()` this way:

```
struct X { };
struct Y : X { };
struct Z : X { };

int main()
{
    static_assert(commonBaseClass<X, Y, Z>(), "!");
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=81d94630b02d222265209126c50b297c-a73d80d9462cfb550c0755cfd96ceec5).

Comment: damn I have to deeply understand that integral constant, second time I see it .. Thank you hope it works!

Comment: @DarioOO: You're welcome. Yes, `integral_constant` is not the most intuitive thing of all, but in fact it is not even hard to get an intuition for it if you play with it a bit. It is basically a struct with a static `value` data member of the type of the integral constant (e.g. `integral_constant<bool, V>` boils down to `struct X { static constexpr bool value = V; /*...some other helpful stuff...*/ }` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) for a reference)